# Node.JS - firebase.auth() is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use firebase Auth on a Node.JS server because Firebase Admin SDK doesn't implement all functions I need. Like `firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)`.

But, when I try to get auth() I get following error:

```
let auth = fire.auth()
                ^
TypeError: fire.auth is not a function
```

My code is very simple:

```
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
let firebase = require('firebase');

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config, "firebase");

let auth = fire.auth()
```

I'm, also, using Firebase Admin SDK for other functions and its auth() works fine.

There is some problem with use regular Firebase SDK on a Node.JS server?

**EDIT:**

I need both SDK because firebase-admin doesn't have functions like `firebase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)` or others.

Also, initializeApp is necessary for select the project in which I would operate.

Comment: Why do you need both the Admin SDK and the Client SDK? Also, what happens if you don't assign `initializeApp` to a variable and just do `firebase.auth()`?

Comment: I think a recent version of the JS SDK had this problem. I'll try upgrading `firebase` to the latest.

Comment: I am face the same issue here, it is still a feature request you can check on link bellow.
the only way to do that up to now is implement on your client side using angularFire2 for example. [Feature request sendPasswordResetEmail](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/labels/feature-request)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Nope, I quit the company for I was working on this before... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and re-installing node_modules. If the problem persists, you can add Firebase Authentication SDK to your script from the CDN:

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>`.

Refer here for the latest version: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup